# Access and add play length of media files with python

Tags: python, video, media

I would like to write a script that walks my media folder and adds the play length of all the files, similar to what iTunes does ("32 days of music").
What I have no clue about, however, is how to access this info from a script.
Are there any libraries that you know of that can do this or how might I be able to do this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is probably to use [mediainfo](http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) and wrap it in a [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) call.

Look for the `Duration`-tag...

Example output:

```
$ mediainfo astrid.mp4 
General
Complete name                            : astrid.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 143 MiB
Duration                                 : 24mn 57s
Overall bit rate                         : 802 Kbps
Writing application                      : Lavf55.21.100

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3.0
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 24mn 57s
Bit rate                                 : 669 Kbps
Width                                    : 640 pixels
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.087
Stream size                              : 119 MiB (83%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 129 r2230 1cffe9f
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=3 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=12 / lookahead_threads=2 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=23.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 3
Mode                                     : Joint stereo
Mode extension                           : MS Stereo
Codec ID                                 : 6B
Duration                                 : 24mn 57s
Duration_LastFrame                       : -17ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Delay relative to video                  : 80ms
Stream size                              : 22.9 MiB (16%)
```